# Set OnClickListeners according to SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I have a view and store sharedPrefs with it. If you click the view the first time, the bool value should be true. If you click it again and if the value  is true, it should be false again.

Here is some code:

```
if(AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().isItClicked(id)){
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().delete(id);
                }
            });
        } else {
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().insert(id);
                }
            });
        }
```

And here are the methods of my Prefs handling:

```
public void insertSingleQuotation(String id) {
        editPrefs.putBoolean(id, true).apply();
        editPrefs.commit();
    }




 public boolean isItClicked(String id) {
        return sharedPrefs.getBoolean(id, false);
    }

    public void deleteSingleQuotation(String id){
        editPrefs.remove(id);
        editPrefs.apply();
        editPrefs.commit();
    }
```

Furthermore I have a PagerAdapter and call isItLiked, if the container isShown. Now, the problem is that the container don't refresh the layout and the sharedPrefs and I have to scroll to any other view and then back to this again, so that instantiateItem and destroyItem are called and the view refreshed.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: post the code on click of which you change status (true/false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a button for action (insert/delete), I wrote the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
    //initialization of views/viewpager and other stuff
    //get bool value from SharedPreferences and set it to the button/ur view
    button.setTag(AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().isItClicked(id));
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //change true to false and vice versa
            boolean bool= !((boolean) v.getTag());
            if(bool){
                AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().delete(id);
            }else{
                AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().insert(id);
            }
            v.setTag(bool);
            //get the current/selected fragment instance and update the views
            //like fragment1.updateBoolean(bool);
        }
    });
    //how to update pager fragment on change of some
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //according to position get the instance of the  fragment and update fragment views
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```